# Quantitative retinal mosaic analysis corroborating better scotopic vision in colorblind individuals

Tags: eye, vision, color-blindness

According to https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0042698997003398, color blind individuals have been shown to have an increased ability to see in very low light.  Has there been any quantitative analysis of the retinal mosaic of color blind vs normal people which would support this (i.e. there is an increased density of rods)?  I tried finding something along these lines but was unable to.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retinal_mosaic for an example visual comparison of a retinal mosaic of cone cells between a colorblind and regular retina - image below with a regular retina on the left.

[image]

(image from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retinal_mosaic#/media/File:ConeMosaics.jpg)